# HAML how to craft this line?

Tags: haml

I got this code

```
%p.date= "Submitted #{time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at)} ago | " |
= link_to "Edit Post", edit_post_path(@post)
```

I get unexpected result:

```
<p class="date">Submitted 10 minutes ago | </p>
<a href="/posts/9/edit">Edit Post</a>
```

I want to get a tag inside p tag:

```
<p class="date">Submitted 10 minutes ago | <a href="/posts/9/edit">Edit Post</a></p>
```

I have also tried this:

```
%p.date= "Submitted #{time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at)} ago | "
  = link_to "Edit Post", edit_post_path(@post)
```

and this:

```
%p.date= "Submitted #{time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at)} ago "
  = "| #{link_to "Edit Post", edit_post_path(@post)}"
```

In both cases I get same error

> Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %p and nested within it.

It seems that haml isn't aware that ending | is withing ruby string?
How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break them in next line with indentation to nest them:

```
%p.date
  = "Submitted #{time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at)} ago | "
  = link_to "Edit Post", edit_post_path(@post)
```